# Getting multiple data from model

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

Hi I would like to get temp, pressure, humidity, temp_min and temp_max and put this informations into separated editText fields.

My search function:

```
fun search(city: String) {
    disposable =
            weatherApiService.getWeather(city,apiKey)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(
                            {result -> tempTextView.text = "${result.main.temp}"},
                            {error -> Log.e("searchError", error.message)}

                    )
}
```

my model

```
data class TemperatureFrame(val temp: Double,
                       val pressure: Double,
                       val humidity: Int,
                       val temp_min: Double,
                       val temp_max: Double)

data class Temperature(val main: TemperatureFrame)
```

I would like to get something like this for other parameters inside this function

```
{result -> tempTextView.text = "${result.main.temp}"}
{result -> minTempTextView.text = "${result.main.temp_min}"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working

```
{result ->
       tempTextView.text = "${result.main.temp}"
       minTempTextView.text = "${result.main.temp_min}"
 },
```